# Border в DropdownMenuItem

Tags: flutter, dart

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно добавить border с цветом у элементов выпадающего списка DropdownMenuItem?
В описании класса ничего не нашел подходящего...
Так вывожу элементы списка:

```
return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value,),
            );
          })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так? Если дадите пример, будет более понятней.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: DropdownButton<String>(
            items: <String>['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].map((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
                  child: Text(value),
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (_) {},
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: У меня в целом такой же код, он оборачивает виджет с текстом внутри DropdownMenuItem, а нужно что бы сам DropdownMenuItem был с бордером. Можно ли в items у DropdownButton передать другой виджет, не ?

Comment: @ВладиславДементьев нет, только переопределять DropdownMenuItem и делать таким как вам нужен.